# where I can post my request to no removal qt3 libraries from next ubuntu releases?

Tags: qt3

I know that ubuntu takes 'debian sid' packages to bake next ubuntu and I know that Debian developers currently obsoletes qt3-libraries. Unfortunately I'm still need it because in my company we still use qt3 libraries for our project.

Answer (score 2):

Qt3 is **really old** and you should have moved to Qt4 a long while ago. It isn't maintained upstream anymore, so you cannot expect Linux distributions to just maintain it for you.

From [here](http://lists.kde.org/?l=kde-www&m=117187905415364):

> Trolltech will continue to support the Qt 3 series until **July 1st 2007**.

And besides, in Quantal Qt3 is already removed, so you're way too late to start a discussion about the Qt3 removal.

I suggest to put your efforts on either of the options below.

- Port your application [to Qt4](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/porting4.html) or even Qt5 (longer term)
- Maintain a PPA with the Qt3 libraries your own and tell your users to enable that PPA first.
- Move to RHEL. Red Hat supports a release for 10+ years. See their [lifecycle document](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/) mentioning

  > Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and 6 are offered with 10 years of Production Phase support, followed by a three year Extended Life Phase.

  However, I'm not sure if Qt is one of their core packages included in this; Red Hat is a GTK company.
- Live with the fact the product doesn't run on newer distribution versions anymore.

Comment: Thanks for info.... and I know that is old and we starts some time ago porting our application to qt4 but this is huge application and secondly we have to maintain production releases which is based on qt3. And it will be maintained for a very long time (10 years or later) so in a commercial world is not easy 'just remove' 'obsolete' packages... So its a pity that is too late...

Comment: If you need to maintain something for 10 years, then you can't do that with Ubuntu anyway (only 5 years in LTS). You and your customers should realize that the world changes. The only OS I know to support 10+ years is RHEL. See [their lifecycle document](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/).

Comment: Thanks! Currently we use also CentOS, maybe ubuntu extends support for LTS like Microsoft for Windows XP. :-)